# Magento catalog_eav_attribute foreign key fails phpmyadmin

Tags: magento, phpmyadmin

I am trying to do a simple copy of my database using phpmyadmin and I am getting an error seen at this link http://screencast.com/t/WB9WGs6mW

I have tried to dump the database with the disable foreign key option but I still get the same error after importing the database and trying to copy.

I am running magento 1.8.1.0 community just did an update recently from magento 1.8.0.0

Comment: Try to create the db dump using Magento's internal tool. System->Tools->Backup.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the dump with phpMyAdmin, I suggest you to select "Custom" as export method and tick the "Add drop table" statement in the Object creation options.

Otherwise, If you have access to the shell, you can create a dump with the --opt parameter.

```
mysqldump -uuser -p --opt dbname > dumpfile.sql
```

Comment: Will this fix the problem or just cover it up? I am not sure how this will fix the issue. Can you explain further?

I appreciate your input

Comment: Let's suppose that you want to copy Database A to Database B.
You have different scenarios:
1. Database B is empty: the restore should run smoothly without any error
2. Database B is NOT empty: to restore Database A in B, you have to specify in the dump that tables with the same name in the dump, existing in the database, should be dropped and recreated. This is why the use of --add-drop-table statement.

If your scenario is different, please, be more detailed.
Hope it helps

Comment: Yea this did not work. My scenario is 1. I am just trying to copy the database to an empty database and I still get the error.

Comment: I tried with different scenarios and Magento versions.  
Be sure you follow this instructions in phpmyadmin export:  
- Export Method: custom  
- Format specific options: tick Disable foreign keys check  
- in Object creation options: tick Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT statement  
- in Data creation options: tick Truncate table before insert

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry it did not work. I have recreated the database from scratch. I was missing one of the options that you mentioned on my end I belive.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you follow this instructions in phpmyadmin export:

- Export Method: custom
- Format specific options: tick Disable foreign keys check
- in Object creation options: tick Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT statement
- in Data creation options: tick Truncate table before insert

Let me know if it works.